# Remove css class jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I use my code for change css after click icon :

```
$(function () {
  $(".icon-medium.icon-search").click(function () {
    $(".nksub-tab-icon").addClass("newClass", 1000, callback);
  });

  function callback() {
    setTimeout(function () {    
      $(".nksub-tab-icon").removeClass("newClass");
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

My CSS:

```
<style>
  .newClass { background-color:yellow; }
</style>
```

When I click icon change color but after I click but doesn't remove class.
[For test website here](http://wpcard.net/)

I would like change color and after with another click recover start style.

Comment: jQuery's [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) does not have set of arguments as `string name, int delay, function callback`

Comment: Please lookup function definitions before using them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this code in `<script>` tags.

```
$( ".icon-medium.icon-search" ).click(function() {
  $(".nksub-tab-icon").toggleClass("newClass");
});
```

If you want to provide a delay then use the following code

```
$( ".icon-medium.icon-search" ).click(function() {
  $(".nksub-tab-icon").delay(1000).queue(function(next){
    $(this).toggleClass("newClass");
    next();
  });
});
```

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/zgsxoq3v/